# How to detect contacted objects without movement ? (2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to detect contacted objects without movement ? (2D)

For example think two objects like this;
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3gbf.png)

There is no movement and they are like that since beginning.
So there is no Enter/Exit or Including (Stay) event.

All codes that I found;
OnTriggerEnter/Exit/Stay
OnCollisionEnter/Exit/Stay

These are not working.
What can I do to detect ?

Note: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You need to write your own custom collision detection in that case. Depending on what kinds of objects you have, there are different algorithms used to determine collision

Comment: At first disable/enable your colliders, this might work. If not check the distance between two object and decide it if they are colliding or not. Although this will work for homogeneous geometric shapes, circle, cube etc.